# How to pass values in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a function with two params:

```
private void function(LinkedList<String> a, LinkedList<String> b)
```

I'm using Groovy so I also need to call this function in my program:

```
LinkedList<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
LinkedList<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();
list1.add("A");
list1.add("B");
list1.add("C");
list2.add("A");
list2.add("B");
String command = "function(list1, list2)";
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
Object value = shell.evaluate(command);
```

but when I call it and pass the values what I see is:

```
function([A, B, C],[A, B])
```

Of course this is against the java syntax and the compiler returns erros.
Is there a way to pass the real values?

Comment: First, why use `LinkedList` as a parameter instead of just `List`? The Groovy default implementation is `ArrayList`. Also, did you try *actually using strings*? i.e., `function(["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B"])`?

Comment: why not add list1 and list2 to the Binding?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to inline the call (and are writing this in Groovy), you can just declare a new `LinkedList` with a list as an argument:

```
String command = "function(new LinkedList(['A','B', 'C']), new LinkedList(['A', 'B']))";
```

Otherwise you can add them to the binding like @tim_yates said:

```
binding.setProperty("list1", list1);
binding.setProperty("list2", list2);
```